Late notifications on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 6.8.0-40-generic and i seem to be getting the notification alerts for any and all applications late. I notice it the most with slack notifications but that might just be because im getting more notifications from there.
I expect the notification popup to show up immediately but it may not happen until 20 minutes later.
What could be happening here?


I'm having the same problem and have also only noticed it with Slack.

I have the same problem since I've upgraded from 22. Very annoying. It's not only Slack - it's basically any application. What I've found: it seems notifications are stuck - another application issuing a notification might push out an older one.
Running this in the terminal seems to always show a notification instantly: notify-send "Hello!"
Haven't yet pinned the component that might be the culprit.
Will post updates in case I find more.

@andr ye really annoying im still facing the same problem

I definitely get this a lot from Slack, although that's where most of my notifications from from anyway. I've also seen it happen with Flameshot. Testing the notify-send "Hello!" works fine, as @andr said.
